# How to attempt to read from serial port without blocking?

Tags: rust, serial-port

I am creating a FFI library (will be called from plain C code) to control a COM device. My idea was relatively simple: spawn an extra thread which periodically checks for new messages (and parses them etc), and also gets commands from the main thread functions using a channel. So something like this:

```
let (tx, rx) = mpsc::channel();
thread::spawn(move || {
            loop {
              // get commands from main thread(if any) with rx.recv_timeout
              // then read a message from the device with BufReader.read_line
              sleep(..)
            }
        });
```

However this does not work because reading from the BufReader blocks. There is a set_timeout function under serial port, but as far as I can see this timeout only applies to device getting disconnected. So if there is no newline character but the device is still connected, this thread will block forever and ignore the commands it is getting.

Is there any way to check for a new line without blocking like this? Perhaps with a timeout.

Comment: "*My idea was relatively simple: spawn an extra thread which periodically checks for new messages ..., and also gets commands from the main thread*"  -- Maybe you should rethink the functionalities assigned to the threads to allow blocking reads.  If a thread was only responsible for reading asynchronous input from one source, then you wouldn't care if it blocked or not.

Comment: What you want is non-blocking IO like in the [`mio`](https://crates.io/crates/mio) crate. For example, if you are using Linux you set up an `epoll` (event poll) and register one or more files associated with the COM ports you want to watch (something like `/dev/ttyS0`). Then you periodically check the poll for events and act accordingly. The weird part is that despite being called non-blocking the polling will still block, but the benefit is you block over a large group of sockets/files instead of one per thread.

Comment: Commonly you cannot detect that a serial port is connected or not, at least on the OS level. The used protocol can include some life-signs or equivalent measures, though.

Comment: Maybe what you would need is something asynchronous rather than working with threads? That would overcome this blocking issue.

Comment: I have solved this in the end by making an extra thread just for blocking over the bufreader reading, and sending the results back to the original thread. However I feel like there could have been a better solution if anyone would like to provide a full answer.

Comment: @thebusybee the SerialPort crate includes a set_timeout function which seems to timeout if the device on the serial port is disconnected for a while. I am not sure how this is implemented underneath.

Comment: "Disconnected" is the wrong term. As I said, a serial port cannot determine if it is connected to a communication partner. -- On write, depending on the chosen handshake the port might not be able to send, because the receiver signals "not ready for reception." Instead of blocking forever, the write will return with a timeout. -- On read, if less than the requested number of "bytes" (5 to 8 bits) is received, the read will return with a timeout. -- You might want to do some research on the working of serial ports, before you speculate and draw wrong conclusions. ;-)